# ValueError: Row numbers must be between 1 and 1048576

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using python openpyxl to extract specific data from an xlsx file to another xlsx. I defined a function which extracts the data I need and then I ran it using a while loop and told it to stop when it finds an empty cell.

But for some reason it gives me this error: **Row numbers must be between 1 and 1048576**

Here is my code:

```
x=3; y=2; z=4; i=5
def line():
    c1 = ws1.cell(row = z, column = 1)
    ws2.cell(row = y, column = 1).value = c1.value
    c2 = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 2)
    ws2.cell(row = y, column = 2).value = c2.value
    c3 = ws1.cell(row = i, column = x)
    ws2.cell(row = y, column = 3).value = c3.value

while ws1.cell(row=i, column=x+2).value != "":
    line()
    y+=1
    x+=2
    i+=1
else:
    sys.exit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add full error stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell value returns a `None` when there is no data. It will not return `""`. So, the condition is NOT satisfied and the while loop goes on till the last row of excel. Change...

```
while ws1.cell(row=i, column=x+2).value != "":
```

to

```
while ws1.cell(row=i, column=x+2).value is not None:
```

...and the code would run as expected.